# C segmentation fault 11 on recv() function

Tags: c, sockets

I have an issue with C sockets. I have `Segmentation fault: 11` on `recv(int socket, void *buffer, size_t length, int flags);` function. I have printed server ip in connection function. That should mean, that socket is initialized correctly.

Function which uses function recv:

```
int receive_packet(SOCKET *socket, char *packet)
{
    int bytes;
    char data_buffer [2000] = {0};

    bytes = recv(*socket, data_buffer, sizeof(data_buffer), 0);

    if (bytes == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else if (bytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Error: failed to receive packet\n");

        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    else
    {
        memset (packet, 0, bytes);

        strcpy (packet, data_buffer);

        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Main function where is the call to function recv:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SOCKET command_socket;
    int port;
    char *host;
    char *username;
    char *password;
    char *packet = NULL;

    host = argv[1];
    port = atoi(argv[2]);
    username = argv[3];
    password = argv[4];

    printf("BEFORE: %d\n", command_socket);

    command_socket = connect_to_server(host, port);

    printf("AFTER: %d\n", command_socket);

    receive_packet(&command_socket, packet);

    printf("Packet: %s\n", packet);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
BEFORE: 0
Connected successfully.
AFTER: 3
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Any ideas why?!

P.S. My UNIX based operating system is OS X.

Comment: Is SOCKET an integer? Are you sure it is pointing to a valid memory position?

Comment: Show the call, the absolutely most likely error is that you're passing an invalid pointer as the first argument.

Comment: Yes, it is an integer. I think it is, because I used function `connect` with this socket and then printed servers IP address correctly...

Comment: You'll need to make sure the socket is a valid number and has been connected.

Comment: There are many things that could go wrong. Please create a proof of concept program so that we can point to the actual problem. Otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: packet is NULL, you must declare it just like data_buffer...

Comment: function recv doesn't use packet...

Comment: `strcpy (packet, data_buffer);` data_buffer is **not** NUL terminated.

Comment: Ok, I will fix it. But program gets segmentation fault in line `bytes = recv(*socket, data_buffer, sizeof(data_buffer), 0);`

Comment: @JacobJones Are you *sure* it's really crashing in the `recv` call and not the `strcpy`? Have you used a debugger to verify?

Comment: I added line `char *packet = "";`. Now I get `Bus error: 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understand, SOCKET should be of type `int` to represent a file descriptor. And you must have passed a NULL to `receive_packet`, when dereferencing that pointer, you got segment falut, which is the only reason i can thought about why you got a segment falut in recv.

Comment: I have printed socket value before sending it to recv function. It is not NULL...

Comment: @JacobJones In you main function `char *packet = NULL;` and you pass it to `receive_packet`. When you reference it in `receive_packet` with `memset (packet, 0, bytes);` you will got a segment fault.

Comment: No. I get segmentation fault in line `bytes = recv(*socket, data_buffer, sizeof(data_buffer), 0);`. When I comment out this line, it works fine...

Comment: @JacobJones Post complete code in the question, i'll try it on my machine. There should be some other bug in your code which cause this problem, `recv` itself cannot get segment fault.

Comment: I added line `char *packet = "";`. Now I get `Bus error: 10`

Comment: Always allocate memory big enough before you use it. In your case length of packet should be at least `bytes+1`(of course its dynamic and depending how much data you received), just pointing out.

Comment: You mean `memset (packet, 0, bytes+1);`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66491/discussion-between-jujj-and-jacob-jones).

Comment: @JacobJones Commenting out the `recv` call does **not** mean that the segfault is occurring in it. With that line commented out, `bytes` is uninitialized. Quite possibly it is zero, meaning the function will return immediately and never run the `memset` or `strcpy`, so the crash may actually be in one of those calls. You *must* use a debugger to see what is really happening. Making assumptions does not work.